# Sharepoint designer workflow does not automatically start for first list item insert

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

SharePoint designer workflow does not automatically start for first list item insert.

Second item inserted start workflow automatically. What is the problem?

Comment: The first item is created by which account? If its the system account then workflow will not start automatically.

Comment: It is not system account, because second item starts the wf. And I know that Designer wf cannot be started by sys account.

Comment: Check Workflow Timer Jobs. Also look for error/exceptions in the log files.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem and no one at Microsoft can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution for this.  After completing recreating the library identically, I found that the same problem persisted.  After much testing, I found that removing the Required flag for fields that I had set for Required fixed this problem.  Once they were all set to Optional, the problem went away.